# Python script recursively rename all files in folder and subfolders

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I have  a number of different files that need to be renamed to something else. I got this far but I want to have it so that I can have many items to replace and their corresponding replacements rather than type each one out, run the code then retype it again.

UPDATE* Also I need the rename to only change part of the file not the whole thing so if there was a "Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top-Aqeoiu31" it would just change it to "'Cat5e50m1mBED_50m2mBE2U-Aqeoiu31"

```
import os, glob

#searches for roots, directory and files
for root,dirs, files in os.walk(r"H:\My Documents\CrossTalk\\"):
   for f in files:
       if f == "Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top":#string you want to rename
          try:
             os.rename('Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top', 'Cat5e50m1mBED_50m2mBE2U'))
          except FileNotFoundError, e:
             print(str(e))
```

Comment: What is the common replacement in the file name you will be making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this wath you want?

```
import os, glob
#searches for roots, directory and files
#Path
p=r"C:\\Users\\joao.limberger\\Documents\\Nova Pasta"
# rename arquivo1.txt to arquivo33.txt and arquivo2.txt to arquivo44.txt
renames={"arquivo1.txt":"arquivo33.txt","arquivo2.txt":"arquivo44.txt"}
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(p):
   for f in files:
      if f in renames.keys():#string you want to rename
         try:
            os.rename(os.path.join(root , f), os.path.join(root , renames[f]))
            print("Renaming ",f,"to",renames[f])
         except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Check if this is what you want!!!

```
import os, glob
#searches for roots, directory and files
#Python 2.7
#Path 
p=r"C:\\Users\\joao.limberger\\Documents\\Nova Pasta"
#  if the substring in the key exists in the filename, replace the substring 
#   from the value of the key
#   if the key is "o1" and the value is "oPrinc1" and the filename is
#  arquivo1.txt ... The filename will be renamed to "arquivoPrinc1.txt"
renames={"o1":"oPrinc1","oldSubs":"newSubs"}
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(p):
    for f in files:
        for r in renames:
            if r in f:
                newFile = f.replace(r,renames[r],1)
                try:
                    os.rename(os.path.join(root , f), os.path.join(root , newFile))
                    print "Renaming ",f,"to",newFile
                except FileNotFoundError , e:
                    print str(e)
```

Comment: `if f in renames.keys()` => `if f in renames`, more pythonic, faster.

Comment: No that didn't work, it renamed all the files. I want only part of the file renamed. Im sorry if I am confusing you, please look at the update above

Comment: You wan´t to rename based on substring? If the filename contains de first substring then replace this substring in filename by the other?
Sample:
 if the key is "o1" and the value is "oPrinc1" and the filename is arquiv**o1**.txt ... The filename whil be renamed to "arquiv**oPrinc1**.txt"

Comment: Hi @VisualExstasy you see this after i edited the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'd need is a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the replacements, then a small change in your code:

```
import os, glob

name_map = {
     "Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top": 'Cat5e50m1mBED_50m2mBE2U'
}

#searches for roots, directory and files
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"H:\My Documents\CrossTalk"):
   for f in files:
       if f in name_map:
          try:
             os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, name_map[f]))
          except FileNotFoundError, e:
          #except FileNotFoundError as e:  # python 3
             print(str(e))
```

In the name_map, the `key` (string to the left of "`:`") is the name of the file in your filesystem, and the `value` (string to the right of the "`:`") is the name you want to use.

Comment: that won't work: you have to join the `root` dir or `rename` will fail.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hey you helped me on my last script, got any suggestions?

Comment: @RafaelBarros got a syntax error "    os.rename(f, name_map[f]))
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: also `except FileNotFoundError, e` should be `except FileNotFoundError as e` to be python 3 compliant (else you're python 2.5 compliant). And you still have one parenthesis too many in the end. All original errors copied from the OP question to your answer. I'm editing that out :) you'll thank me later. Now I can upvote myself :)

Comment: @Engineer should be OK now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Im running python 2.5 and still get an error even when running on 2.7 it just hangs

Comment: "an error" isn't good enough. Tell us what's the problem. And the fact it 'hangs' is that maybe there are a lot of files there...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The error was not compatible with python2.5